# Pandas - Using 'ffill' on values other than Na

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, pandasql

Is there a way to use `ffill` method on values that are not `NaN`?

I have `NaN` in my dataframe, but I have added these `NaN` using

```
addNan = sample['colA'].replace(['A'], 'NaN')
```

So this is what my DataFrame, `df` looks like

```
ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD
 B      A     A    C
 NaN    B     A    A
 C      D     D    A
 NaN    A     A    B
```

And I'm trying to fill these `NaN` using `ffill` , so they are populated by the last known value.

`fill = df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)`

This doesn't make a difference, also tried `Na` instead of `NaN`

Comment: It looks like need `np.nan` - `addNan = sample['colA'].replace(['A'], np.nan)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need first replace `NaN` to `np.nan`, because `NaN` is only text:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print (sample)
  ColA ColB ColC ColD
0    B    A    A    C
1    A    B    A    A
2    C    D    D    A
3    A    A    A    B

sample['ColA'] = sample['ColA'].replace(['A'], np.nan)
print (sample)
  ColA ColB ColC ColD
0    B    A    A    C
1  NaN    B    A    A
2    C    D    D    A
3  NaN    A    A    B
```

If use `inplace = True`, it return `None`, but inplace fill values:

```
sample.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
#sample.ffill(inplace = True)
print (sample)
  ColA ColB ColC ColD
0    B    A    A    C
1    B    B    A    A
2    C    D    D    A
3    C    A    A    B
```

Comment: Thanks this works - but what if I wanted to fill values other than NaN?

Comment: If dont need use `fillna` it means replace `NaN`, you can use `sample['ColA'] = sample['ColA'].replace(['A'], 'new_val')` or maping by dict `sample['ColA'] = sample['ColA'].map({'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B2'})`