# Rolling 10 minutes recent value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, analytics

I wish to create a new column based upon the given column values.
Each row of the "CurrentValue" column should be equal to the 'InitialValue' Column's recent most value in the last 10 minutes.

Here is the data set (csv format):

```
date,InitialValue
3/20/2020 1:00,
3/20/2020 1:01,
3/20/2020 1:02,
3/20/2020 1:03,
3/20/2020 1:04,
3/20/2020 1:05,
3/20/2020 1:07,
3/20/2020 1:12,
3/20/2020 1:13,
3/20/2020 1:15,
3/20/2020 1:16,555
3/20/2020 1:17,
3/20/2020 1:19,
3/20/2020 1:20,
3/20/2020 1:22,
3/20/2020 1:26,576
3/20/2020 1:27,
3/20/2020 1:28,
3/20/2020 1:34,
3/20/2020 1:35,
3/20/2020 1:36,
3/20/2020 1:37,
3/20/2020 1:38,577
3/20/2020 1:40,
3/20/2020 1:42,
3/20/2020 1:43,
3/20/2020 1:44,
3/20/2020 1:45,
3/20/2020 1:51,
```

Here is the sample output:

```
date,InitialValue,CurrentValue
2020-03-20 01:00:00,,
2020-03-20 01:01:00,,
2020-03-20 01:02:00,,
2020-03-20 01:03:00,,
2020-03-20 01:04:00,,
2020-03-20 01:05:00,,
2020-03-20 01:07:00,,
2020-03-20 01:12:00,,
2020-03-20 01:13:00,,
2020-03-20 01:15:00,,
2020-03-20 01:16:00,555.0,555.0
2020-03-20 01:17:00,,555.0
2020-03-20 01:19:00,,555.0
2020-03-20 01:20:00,,555.0
2020-03-20 01:22:00,,555.0
2020-03-20 01:26:00,576.0,576.0
2020-03-20 01:27:00,,576.0
2020-03-20 01:28:00,,576.0
2020-03-20 01:34:00,,576.0
2020-03-20 01:35:00,,576.0
2020-03-20 01:36:00,,576.0
2020-03-20 01:37:00,,
2020-03-20 01:38:00,577.0,577.0
2020-03-20 01:40:00,,577.0
2020-03-20 01:42:00,,577.0
2020-03-20 01:43:00,,577.0
2020-03-20 01:44:00,,577.0
2020-03-20 01:45:00,,577.0
2020-03-20 01:51:00,,
```

UPDATE: This is not the correct answer [Pandas - Using 'ffill' on values other than Na](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915330/pandas-using-ffill-on-values-other-than-na)

UPDATE 2: Output Data updated

Comment: Your sample output doesn't match your description, since values are filled forward for more than 10 minutes. Can you either update the sample output or clarify the question?

Comment: updated the output data sample

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['CurrentValue']=np.NaN

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')
ten_minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

for row in df.iterrows():
    df_timed = df[row[0]-ten_minutes: row[0]]
    for k in df_timed.iloc[::-1].iterrows():
        if not pd.isnull(k[1]['InitialValue']):
            df.at[row[0],'CurrentValue'] = k[1]['InitialValue']
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that df['date'] is of type datetime. If it is string, first convert it via

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

**Solution 1** (shorter):

Use `pd.DataFrame.rolling` with a 10min offset.

```
df = df.set_index('date')
df['CurrentValue'] = df.rolling('10min',closed='both')['InitialValue'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill()[-1])
```

**Solution 2** (faster):

Find date and value of last observation for each row

```
# get date of last observation
lastDate = df['date'].mask(pd.isnull(df['InitialValue']))
lastDate = lastDate.ffill()
    
# fill latest observation into CurrentValue if lastDate is less than 600s old
seconds_since_last = (df['date'] - lastDate).dt.total_seconds()
df['CurrentValue'] = df['InitialValue'].ffill().mask(seconds_since_last > 600)
```